# Relative path of file in jasperserver

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

**In jasperStudio  we are passing the absolute path of the file in the following manner**:

```
<parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.String">
<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\Users\\ABC\\Desktop\\dynamicSubreport\\ABC.xml"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

**Here in jasperstudio it’s working fine.**

*While in jasperserver we need to pass the relative path instead absolute. In jasperserver we have added these xml template under Resources and tried calling the same in following way*

```
<parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.String">
              <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["repo:ABC.xml"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

We also uploaded these files under reports folder in jasperserver and tried calling in the following way:

```
<parameter name="Parameter1" class="java.lang.String">
<defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["repo:reports/ABC.xml"]]></defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

None of the above ways worked out in jasperserver. So any suggestions or feedback on the above scenario would be very helpful.